# Can't set container's color AND BoxShadow's color

Tags: android, flutter

Android Studio 3.6

I need container with orange background color AND gray shadow.

Snippet:

```
const double BOX_SHADOW_BLUR_RADIUS = 8.0;
const double BOX_SHADOW_SPREAD_RADIOUS = BOX_SHADOW_BLUR_RADIUS / 4;
const double BOX_SHADOW_OFFSET_X = BOX_SHADOW_BLUR_RADIUS / 2;
const double BOX_SHADOW_OFFSET_Y = BOX_SHADOW_BLUR_RADIUS / 2;

 Widget _createScanCheckContainer() {
    return new ClipRRect(
        borderRadius:
BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(Constants.ROUNDED_CORNER_RADIUS)),
            child: new Container(
                height: 56.0,
                decoration: _createBoxDecoration(),
                color: Colors.orange,
                child: Stack(children: [
                  new Positioned(
                    left: Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN,
                    top: Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN,
                    bottom: Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN,
                    child: new Image.asset('assets/images/ic_scan_ticket.png'),
                  ),
                  new Expanded(
                      child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text("Scan receipt",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19.0, color: Colors.white)),
                  ))
                ])));
      }


    BoxDecoration _createBoxDecoration() {
        return new BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.8),
              blurRadius: Constants.BOX_SHADOW_BLUR_RADIUS,
              // has the effect of softening the shadow
              spreadRadius: Constants.BOX_SHADOW_SPREAD_RADIOUS,
              // has the effect of extending the shadow
              offset: Offset(
                Constants.BOX_SHADOW_OFFSET_X, // horizontal, move right 10
                Constants.BOX_SHADOW_OFFSET_Y, // vertical, move down 10
              ))
        ]);
      }
```

But I get error:

```
 cannot provide both a color and a decoration
```

Comment: add `color` to `BoxDecoration`

Comment: @pskink Error is gone, but not show shadow

Comment: are you sure that `blurRadius` is correct? not 0 for example?

Comment: @pskink I updated my post. It's not 0

Comment: ok, you use clipping - it will not work - your clip clips the shadow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Remove color: from _createScanCheckContainer
- remove cliprrect
- add color and border radius to _createBoxDecoration

```
Widget _createScanCheckContainer() {
    return new Container(
        height: 56.0,
        decoration: _createBoxDecoration(),

        child: Stack(children: [
          new Positioned(
            left: 5,
            top: 5,
            bottom: 5,
            child: new Image.asset('assets/images/ic_scan_ticket.png'),
          ),
          new Expanded(
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text("Scan receipt",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19.0, color: Colors.white)),
              ))
        ]));
  }


 BoxDecoration _createBoxDecoration() {
        return new BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.orange,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),

        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.8),
              blurRadius: Constants.BOX_SHADOW_BLUR_RADIUS,
              // has the effect of softening the shadow
              spreadRadius: Constants.BOX_SHADOW_SPREAD_RADIOUS,
              // has the effect of extending the shadow
              offset: Offset(
                Constants.BOX_SHADOW_OFFSET_X, // horizontal, move right 10
                Constants.BOX_SHADOW_OFFSET_Y, // vertical, move down 10
              ))
        ]);
```

Comment: Updated answer to address the problem

Comment: borderRadius not defined in BoxShadow

Comment: Sorry, you need to set it in BoxDecoration, not BoxShadow